# Defining an independent variable?

Tags: research-design

I am conducting a small study where one class is taught similar (but not the same) concepts over two separate lessons.
The first lesson, the teacher will deliver the lesson to the class.
The second lesson, the students will watch instructional videos without teacher intervention.
A post test is conducted after each lesson to see if the way the content was delivered showed an increase in student learning.
So from the reading I have done I would think:

I have a control group: explicit instruction from the teacher

I have an intervention group: content delivered through instructional videos

Student learning is my dependant variable

My independent variable consists of two levels, the control and the intervention ie: the way the lesson is delivered.

Does this also mean my independent variable is actually the two groups - the control group and the intervention group?

Just trying to get my terminology right so I don’t look like a total twit when proposing this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Cross Validated James.

I get the following from your description

- You have a set of $N$ students, which we can index by $i = 1, 2, \dots, N$
- Your outcome variable, let's call it $Y_i$, measures student learning (i.e. the test score)
- Your independent variable, lets call it $T_i$ is either "control", if the student got instructed by the teacher or "intervention" if the lesson was delivered by video, which we could numerically represent by $0$ and $1$

If you were to give the two groups of students a variable as well, it would just just be exactly equal to $T_i$. Treatment and group are the same.

Comment: Perfect Martin! Thanks heaps!